# Where can I find a reference for data types in uniforms and attributes for Three.js (WebGL)?

Tags: arrays, types, three.js, webgl

I'm using Three.js and custom shaders along with uniform and attribute values, and my question is about where to find a list of all the types for the various attribute and uniform values (such as as listed for the textures, "t"; vector3s, "v3"; and float, "f" below).

```
this.customUniforms = 
    {
        texture1: { type: "t", value: discTexture }, // <<< looking for a reference that lists all the valid types such as "t", "f" and "v3"
        texture2: { type: "t", value: hatchTexture },
        mixAmount:   { type: "f", value: 0.0 }
    };

this.customAttributes = 
    {
       endPosition: { type: "v3", value: [] }
    };
```

Comment: My first google answer for "threejs uniform type": [Uniforms types](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types) (in the three.js wiki)

Comment: @Volune Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for - goodness knows why I couldn't manage to provoke it out of the googles. ;) If you want to write up the link I'll approve your answer.

Comment: those two links are precious too : https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/  and http://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf